# Call a function once or every time as needed on the same page in PHP?

Tags: php, function

Below is a sample PHP function.

```
function showPizza() {
     // Prepare ingredients..
     // Make pizza...
     // Bake pizza...
     // Cute pizza...

     return pizza...
}
```

On one page, pizza needs to be shown several times. Is it a good practice to call the function only once, assign value to a variable and use the variable as many times as needed as following?

```
<?php $pizza = showPizza(); ?>

<div id="left-session"><?= $pizza ?></div>
<div id="middle-session"><?= $pizza ?></div>
<div id="right-session"><?= $pizza ?></div>
```

Or call the function every time it is needed as following?

```
<div id="left-session"><?= showPizza(); ?></div>
<div id="middle-session"><?= showPizza(); ?></div>
<div id="right-session"><?= showPizza(); ?></div>
```

Is the former solution better for the performance or it does not matter?

Comment: please add your output next to your `div` what you need there ? and also share your complete code for `showPizza()`

Comment: @C2486 The function will always execute the same code and return the same value for the three <div>s above. Does it matter what the complete code is inside the function, related to this question?

Comment: Then  using a variable would be better than calling function each time.

Comment: _"Does it matter what the complete code is inside the function"_ - Yes. It _definitely_ does. If the function, for example, makes a bunch of HTTP requests, calls some database or does a bunch of complex stuff (that uses memory/CPU/network traffic or similar), you want to save the result, or it will to that on every single function call.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson so what you are saying is, if a function executes a few lines of code, it won't matter to call it several times on one page, but if a function executes a bunch of heavy code, calling it only one time and assign value to a variable for reusing?

Comment: Better to be consistent. If the function is expected to return the same result on each call, just store it in a variable. Then you only need to change it once, if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

For the case described by you it will be best if you call the function once and assign value to a variable and use it in rest of the page.

Answer (score 1):

If the value that `showPizza` returns is always the same, call it once and store it in a variable. PHP have a slight cost in function calls and if you have any type of logic in the function, that will also add up on the cost of executing the function.
Storing the value in a variable will hence make the cost a lot less and preferable as long as the value is not different for each function call.

Answer (score 0):

They are completely different, I will show an example to you

```
$a=2;
$b=2;
function sumofAandB(){
    return $a+$b;
}
$value = sumofAandB();
$a=9;
echo sumofAandB(); //The output is 11
echo $value; //The output is 4
```

So the output will be different but if you don't change a and b after calling the function and store the value to your variable then it does not have any differences in result

**BUT** : It has some differences in the time it runs, If you use the function every time you need the return value you are re calculating the value and so you need more time

And if you store the value in a variable it needs less time cause you run the function once.

*In your situation I don't see any change to result of showPizza() return value so it's better to store it in a variable and use it as many as you want*

Comment: _Note:_ Just to be picky, when you call `sumofAandB()`, you would get two _"Undefined variable"_ warnings, since the variables `$a` and `$b` doesn't exist in the functions scope.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You are right and I voted your comment but it was just an example :)))

Comment: I understand. But if the OP (or future visitors) are total beginners, they might actually be confused. Always write as accurate code as possible in answers.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that it's bad practice to allow things outside of a function to make the return value behave differently like that. Rather use parameters in that case :)